# Differentiate this function with $e^{-t}$

Tags: calculus

Suppose $t^4 - e^{-t}$.

How do I differentiate this function?

I know that $t^4 = 4t^3$.

Does $e^{-t} = te^{-t-1}$ ?

Comment: $\frac {d(e^{-t})}{dt}=-e^{-t}$ and why did you add the tag differential equation?

Comment: $t^4$ is not equal to $4t^3$, unless $t=0$ or $t=4$.  $e^{-t}$ is not equal to $te^{-t-1}$, unless $t=e$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{d}{dt}e^t=e^t$$
$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{at}=ae^{at}$$
$$\text{set }a=-1$$
$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{-1\times t}=-1\times e^{-1\times t}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{-t}=-e^{-t}$$

---

You can 'term-wise' derive:

$\frac{d}{dt}(t^4 - e^{-t})=\frac{d}{dt}(t^4) - \frac{d}{dt}(e^{-t})=4t^3-(-e^t)=4t^3+e^{-t}$

---

Please don't mix up differential operators and multiplication by $1$.

$t^4\ne4t^3$, but $\frac{d}{dt}(t^4)=4t^3$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $(e^{-t})' = -e^{-t}, (t^4)' = 4t^3 $

Comment: On the exam, it was rather 
A) 4t^3 + e^-t 
b) 4t^3 - e^-t
c) 4t^3 - e^-t-1
d) 4t^3 + e^-t-1 

i picked 4t^3 - e^-t
Not sure it was correct

Comment: your pick is correct.

Comment: @BRIC-Fan He did not pick correctly. The correct answer was A because the second term was negative and its derivative was negative. It would become positive after taking the derivative.

Comment: Thanks. Also, does -e^-t changes to +e^-t? or it stay the same? 
I know that i can't differentiate e^x, but does it work with e^-t too?

Comment: @DonDo You can differentiate $e^x$. It differentiates to $e^x$. Just because it doesn't change after differentiation doesn't mean you can't do it. The derivative of $e^{-x}$ is demonstrated across multiple answers on this question.

Comment: @BRIC-Fan: Thanks for your response. I was stuck between (-)e or (+)e.

Comment: @DonDo [redacted...]$e^{-t}$ derives to $-e^{-t}$ and $-e^{-t}$ derives to $e^{-t}$. Apologies that was rude, I misread your last comment as 'I *am* stuck between'

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge: Sorry, english is my 2nd language. I'm not trolling.

Comment: @Committingtoachallenge: Oh, so i supposed to choose d) 4t^3 + e^-t. Now i understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

$(e^{-t})'=-e^{-t}$ that's your answer. But remember that $x^n$ and $a^x$ are different functions and should be treated differently. Actually $(a^x)'=a^xln(a)$. Also to find your function you need to notice that it is complicated function and that's where the minus sign comes from. $$(e^{-t})'=e^{-t}ln(e)*(-t)'=-e^{-t}$$

Answer (score 0):

From one of the comments you made, I though it was a good idea to add this hint:

$$
(f + g)' = f' + g'
$$

So,

$$
(t^4 - e^{-t})' =(t^4)' - (e^{-t})'
$$